# Python peewee: refer self value in a model class for hybrid property

Tags: python, model, peewee

I've a class:

```
class FixedTransaction(Transaction):
    except_dates = JSONField(null=True)
    active = BooleanField(null=True)
    exp_day = IntegerField()

    _exp_date_month = None
    _exp_date_year = None

    @hybrid_property
    def is_exp(self):
        return datetime(2018, 5, self.exp_day)
```

I need to get the value of that property (exp_day) that is a integer value, but it returns an instance of IntergerField:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ginoepri/Development/Python/pkg/console.py", line 85, in <module>
    fixeds = FixedTransaction.select().where(FixedTransaction.is_exp > datetime(2010, 5, 1))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/playhouse/hybrid.py", line 27, in __get__
    return self.expr(instance_type)
  File "/home/ginoepri/Development/Python/pkg/models/fixed_transaction.py", line 20, in is_exp
    return datetime(2018, 5, self.exp_day)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type IntegerField)
```

How do I refer to the real value (a interger in this case) of the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessed as a class attribute, then the field itself is used. You need to access it as an instance attribute in order to retrieve the value of `self.exp_day`.